# Inserting listview items individually into database as new entries

Tags: sqlite, listview, for-loop, javafx

## Tl:dr

I have a listview with items. I want each individual item inserted into my sqlite database as a new entry. Right now, I am only able to insert all items into the database as a single entry.

I am able to populate the list from my database correctly. If I manually input the items in the SqliteStudio. The added items will show up as an individual item.

## Code settings up the list

```
private ObservableList listchosedescription;
listchosedescription  = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
this.descriptionschosen.setItems(listchosedescription);
```

## Code for populating the list

```
while (result.next()) {
listchosedescription.add(result.getString("description"));
}
descriptionschosen.setItems(listchosedescription);
```

## Faulty code for adding listview items to the database

```
Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
PreparedStatement statement2 = conn.prepareStatement(sqlDesInsert);    
statement2.setString(1, String.valueOf(descriptionschosen.getItems()));
statement2.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(labelidnew.getText()));
statement2.execute();
```

From looking online. I think that I need a ***for-loop*** counting the individual items in the list.

```
for(int i = listchosedescription.size(); i != 0; i--){
```

Then I need to add each individual entry to a ***batch*** and then execute the batch.

I also understand how to get a single item from the listview. So I feel a little stuck, hence I thought I would post for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = listchosedescription.size(); i != 0; i--) {
                statement2.setString(1, String.valueOf(listchosedescription.subList(i - 1, i)));
                statement2.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(labelidnew.getText()));
                statement2.addBatch();
            }
            statement2.executeBatch();
```

In this **for-loop**, I have three statements:

1. I create an integer (i) which counts the **size()** of my observableList.
2. I run the loop as long as the **size()** is not equal to 0 (should probably be as long as it is larger than zero).
3. I decrease my integer (i) by 1 each time the loop is run.

Inside the loop, I add my two statements as I normally would. But the values from the observableList are accessed by using its subList. I acess the location using my integer (i).

1. **i-1** will make sure I reach the correct fromIndex.
2. **i** will make sure I reach the correct toIndex.

Lastly, I add to the batch inside the loop and execute the batch after the loop.

Comment: I don't understand the `subList` part of your code. Why not use `listchosedescription.get(i)`? It's like you complicated the `for-loop`.

Comment: Interesting, Sedrick. I am only starting out, so I do complicate stuff it seems.